# Why are my sitemap links not landing on all their named anchors?

Tags: hyperlink, anchor, sitemap

I've just manually completed a sitemap for my dreamweaver 8 website: http://www.ggordontowerofbabel.co.cc  The first 2 pages are fine, with all the links landing just at the spot I want them to.

However, on the 3rd page, they land on the spot, but as soon as the page is fully loaded, it jumps off indiscriminately to another part of the page? This is only a problem once it is loaded onto the server for anyone to access. However, all is fine locally, where only, "MyMediaPage.htm#MyFilm" is applied to the link, but once on the server, I add the full url http://www.ggordontowerofbabel.co.cc//MyMediaPage.htm#MyFilm
Again, all is fine on the first 2 pages on the server, and I'm using the same method.

After removing code from the body tag, it helped only partially. However, now the link lands on the next named anchor instead, almost as catch-up. So, while it may briefly land on its target, it still shoots onto the previous or next one. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The # anchor fragment is for relative links within a page? Or did I misunderstand the question? (You could also consider using a sitemapper tool to generate your HTML sitemaps? Do you get same error then?)